# How to convert multiple .xlsx files in to .csv using pandas and globe

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have a folder `JanuaryDataSentToResourcePro` that contain multiple .xlsx files. 
I want to iterate through folder and convert all of them into .csv and keep the same file name.

For that I'm trying to implement glob, but getting an error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

```
import glob
excel_files = glob('*xlsx*')

for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(r'''C:\Users\username\Documents\TestFolder\JanuaryDataSentToResourcePro\ResourceProDailyDataset_01_01_2018.xlsx''', 'ResourceProDailyDataset')
    df.to_csv(out)
```

I am new to python. Does it look right?

UPDATE:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
excel_files = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel, 'ResourceProDailyDataset')
    df.to_csv(out)
```

But still not converting convert .xlsx to .csv

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The glob package should be used like:

```
import glob
f = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
```

The glob is not a method but glob.glob is.

========================================

```
import glob
excel_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/username/Documents/TestFolder/JanuaryDataSentToResourcePro/*.xlsx') # assume the path
for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel) # if only the first sheet is needed.
    df.to_csv(out)
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt give me an error anymore, but .xlsx files has not been converted to .csv for some reason.

Comment: the read_excel in your loop only read "'C:\Users\username\Documents\TestFolder\JanuaryDataSentToResourcePro\ResourceProDailyDataset_01_01_2018.xlsx". You need put excel here instead of this particular file name.

Comment: But how will it know which folder to go?

Comment: I add the solution for you and please vote if it's ok.

Comment: If only one sheet in each excel files, you can  simply ignore it.

Comment: Got it. Sorry for confusion! Thanks for your help Alex!

Comment: How come you a Senior Data Analyst and only registered on this website 23 days ago? :)

Comment: I just read the posts but never asked or contributed until my friends said I should do it. LOL

Comment: You have great friends LOL!

Comment: They like your comment.